# Command does not seem to follow path variable

Tags: path

I verified the last entry in the PATH variable is

```
C:\MinGW_b\bin
```

I veried that in that location is the executable

```
g++
```

However when I type in

```
g++
```

I get

```
g++ is not recognized...
```

Verified g++ runs if I am in c:\MinGW\bin

Comment: Verify the path within your batch file, by echoing it or something.  The path is/can be user-specific.  If the batch file runs as another user (such as administrator), then the path may be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the path variable, a semicolon must come directly after the last path entry.  I just tried to reproduce this and could not.  It works with out a semicolon or with a semicolon.